# Merge un-tracked folder into a tracked Git repository

Tags: git

I've recently moved all my projects over from Subversion to Git. Thinking everything was all fine and dandy, I continued on developing one of my projects like usual without realising (until now), that I had been modifying the files in the old project directory instead of the new Git tracked directory.

The Git repo is upto date and has every commit including the commit used in the working directory of the old project.

**EDIT:** To clarify, both folders have identical structure and code, simply one has changes that are newer than the HEAD of the Git repo. (The Git Repo has not had any changes to it since).

Is it possible, and how do I, merge changes from my other, untracked folder, into my new Git tracked folder? I want to merge the changes in without messing too much up. What would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think that what you want to achieve is pretty safe. But **do not** delete the old project directory or make any changes to it until you are sure that all the changes you want to be tracked are tracked.

Assumptions:

- You are ok with tracking all the changes you have made to the old project directory in one single commit

At your Git repository, create a backup branch. For convenience sake, we'll just call it backup:

```
git branch backup
```

Then, copy and paste everything from your old project directory to the Git repository. You can do a `git status` or `git diff` or something along those lines to inspect the changes. Try building your project and running the test suite.

If you think something has gone wrong, you can always do a `git reset --hard HEAD` to reset the changes to the git repository to get back the contents before you copied and pasted the old repository over.

If something has gone terribly wrong, you can always delete the current branch, and create a new branch (in fact, a clone of that branch) from the `backup` branch made earlier.

Once you are satisfied, do a `git commit -as` or similar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, however I wasn't sure what would happen with line ending normalizations and .gitignore files etc. Ill give this a shot! Thanks

Comment: Ahh, haha, thats something I didn't see. Log files... The software generates log files when run, and obviously, when we Git2Svn'ed it, it didn't pull those log files into the git repo. I guess I'll have to add some new .gitignore rules!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thankyou! (And hey, .gitignore already ignores .log files :P)

Comment: Sort of off topic, but do you know of any way to commit individual lines? There is a large amount of changes here I'd like to split up...

Comment: there is `git add -p` which allows you to select subsections to add to the staging/index. but then it doesnt really allow line by line addition, as far as i know. but i've heard that emacs has this plugin called `magit` that seems to do it. but i'm not an emacs user so i don't know much. try googling / asking another question on so? afraid i can't help much here.

Comment: Thanks :) The GitHub for Mac app has the feature, sadly the GitHub for Windows client (which I use) doesn't...